# PDF/A broken when signing using a certified signature

Tags: itext, pdfa

When signing a PDF/A-2a using a certified signature, the PDF/A is broken.
The errors that appear are:

- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestLocation'.
- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestMethod'.
- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestValue'.

If I sign the same PDF/A-2a using a non certified signature, then the Digestxxx errors don't appear. So I suppose the problem is related to certified signature.

I was using iText version 5.4.5 and, reading release notes, I found that version 5.5.4 seemed to have solved this problem.
Then I changed to version 5.5.4 but no luck. The same errors appear.
In fact, using version 5.5.4 I have two more errors when signing PDF/A:

- An end text operator is missing.
- A begin text operator is missing.

Do you know how can I know where should the missing text operator be inside the PDF ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:
I've been debugging itext and the problem seems to be in the version detection.
The PDF is version 1.7, but when entering in this condition (in PdfSignatureAppearance.java) in order to determine if Digestxxx fields have to be writen, the version returned is 4.

```
if (writer.getPdfVersion().getVersion() < PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6)
```

The stamper was created using PdfStamper.createSignature in append mode with version parameter equal to "\0" in order to keep the same version as the original document (1.7).

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have updated to version 5.5.7 and the result has been the same than using version 5.5.4. Again, if I sign the same PDF/A-2a using a non certified signature, then the Digestxxx errors don't appear.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question and your pivotal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the initial three errors you got:

- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestLocation'.
- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestMethod'.
- The dictionary must not contain the key 'DigestValue'.

I've applied a fix for this to iText. This was indeed a bug in iText. The issue was that PdfStamper ignored the provided version if you were using append mode. That made it default to version 1.4. Which, as you already discovered, messed up PDF/A2-a documents in PdfSignatureAppearance.

I was unable to reproduce the begin and end text errors you reported. If you could show us your code and input PDF, then we'll take a look at it.